# Can we port the .NET Compact - Windows CE application to Xamarin application for Android platform?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, compact-framework

I have a query regarding the .NET Standard 2.0 implementation. As per my current understanding, the existing applications developed using a .NET framework (Traditional BCL) can be able to port into Xamarin based application for Android platform.

Likewise, can we port the existing application developed using .NET Compact Framework for Windows CE to Xamarin application for Android Platform? How much feasibility is available in API prospect? Please let me know answers.

Comment: That is a really broad question and it really depends upon what CF/CE apis you are using, whether it is a GUI-based app, what hardware features you are using, etc...

Answer (score 1):

.NET 2.0 Standard contains more APIs than .NET CF. The UI will not be transferable at all, you will need to build that from scratch.

You may get some reuse out of your existing behind the scenes C# code, but that is largely dependent on what type of code you have.

However, it is likely going to be much quicker to start from scratch. .NET CF is very outdated.

Comment: Thank you for your answers Adam Pedley and  SushiHangover. I have a Windows CE embedded application and it has the features like accessing the CAN, GPIO, I2C and some Power management features. In some places we used the PINVOKE to touch the Native system. Those things will be able to port directly to Xamarin? I have noted your reply regarding the GUI code. Thanks again.

Comment: You won't be able to port any PINVOKE's unfortunately. With the other things, I am not sure how you are connecting to them. Because you are diving deep into the system's hardware, I think you might find, you will have to write a lot of things for each platform. Not sure on what you would be doing with Power Management features. The Mobile OS normally handles that for you, and you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam Pedley. Now I am understood, the start from scratch will be good for this kind of project as per your suggestion. For CAN and GPIO interfaces, we could develop a JAVA (JAR) or Android (ARR) library and then bind in to my Xamarin project will be the good options. Thank you for your prompting response.